# How can I capture the name or reg_no of the book in this list?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on a library system. I am unable to get the registration number of a book/books to be returned back to library...
My intention is to click on `Return` which captures the book name for return processing.. With what I have, when I `print(book)` it returns None meaning nothing has been taken from the click
My models

```
class Books(models.Model):
    DEPARTMENT = (
        ('COM', 'Computer'),
        ('ELX', 'Electronics'),
        ('CIV', 'Civil'),
        ('BBS', 'Business'),
        ('MSC', 'Miscellaneous'),
    )
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_books = models.IntegerField()
    book_detail = models.TextField(default='text')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=DEPARTMENT)

    def Claimbook(self):
        if self.no_of_books>1:
            self.no_of_books=self.no_of_books-1
            self.save()
        else:
            print("not enough books to Claim")

    def Addbook(self):
        self.no_of_books=self.no_of_books+1
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_name
class Return(models.Model):
    return_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    borrowed_item = models.ForeignKey(Issue,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
def new_issue(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        i_form = IssueForm(request.POST)
        if i_form.is_valid():
            name = i_form.cleaned_data['borrower_id']
            book = i_form.cleaned_data['book_id']
            i_form.save(commit=True)
            books = Books.objects.get(book_name=book)#Get a book names as selected in the dropdown
            semest = Student.objects.get(name=name).semester#Get a student with a semester as selected in the dropdown
            departm = Student.objects.get(name=name).depart
            Books.Claimbook(books)
            return redirect('new_issue')
    else:
        i_form = IssueForm()
    semest = None
    departm = None
    sem_book = Semester.objects.filter(sem=semest, depart=departm)
    return render(request, 'libman/new_issue.html', {'i_form': i_form, 'sem_book': sem_book})
```

The return view

```
def return_book(request):
    book = request.GET.get('book_pk')
    print(book)
    books = Books.objects.get(id=book)
    #b_id = r_form.cleaned_data['borrower_id']
    Books.Addbook(books)
    Issue.objects.filter(borrower_id=1, id=book).delete()
    return render(request,'libman/view_issue.html',{'issue':issue})
```

The template that displays the borrowed books with a link to return beside each book.

```
{% if issue %}
  <table class="layout">
    <thead>
      <th>Reg No.</th>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Book Name</th>
      <th>Issue Date</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
  {% for borrow in issue %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ borrow.borrower_id.student_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ borrow.borrower_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ borrow.book_id }}</td>
      <td>{{ borrow.issue_date }}</td>
      <td name='book_pk'><a href="{% url 'return_book' %}">Return</a> </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
  {% else %}
    <p> There are no books registered. </p>
  {% endif %}
```

Issue model

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    borrower_id = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_id = models.ForeignKey(Books,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly - I believe you need to pass the borrow.book_id to the return view. so the return view knows which book you want return

in your template add the variable book_pk as follows

`<td name='book_pk'><a href="{% url 'return_book' book_pk = borrow.book_id  %}">Return</a> </td>`

also you need to update your urls.py file to accept the new variable something like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('returnbook/<book_pk>/', return_book),
]
```

but the above will need to also update your view function to handle the new passed argument and fetch the object etc..

```
def return_book(request,book_pk):
```

Or

you can add a form with a submit button

```
<form action="{% url 'return_book' %}">
  <label for="book_id">Borrowed Book_id</label>
  <input type="text" id="book_id" name="book_pk" value="{{ borrow.book_id }}" disabled><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

it should work with your current code i think

Comment: What if I want to have the book_pk as a relational path i.e <td name='book_pk'><a href="{% url 'return_book' book_pk = borrow.book_id.reg_no %}">Return</a> </td>. It complains of no reverse match for the reg_no. How would I modify???

Comment: @fakeMake not sure if i understand . what are you trying to do

Comment: Can I write book_pk = borrow.book_id.reg_no and it works instead of book_pk = borrow.book_id.... book_id gives me the name of the book and therefore if I click return it returns all the books borrowed with that name, so getting reg_no can help me retrieve only a single book with the reg_no for return... How can I achieve this???? Or is there away I can have the book_id return reg_no instead of book_name from the model or view????

Comment: @fakeMake post the "Issue" model it seems missing from your code . so we  can understand the relationships

Comment: Added the issue model

Comment: @fakeMake hmm the naming you have bit confusing returning the object id back to the view.. try ` <td name='book_pk'><a href="{% url 'return_book' book_pk = borrow.book_id.id  %}">Return</a> </td>`